# Tikz: how to position arrows emanating from a sentence?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, sentence

I wish to create the following diagram (the arrows could be made shorter):

[image]

Here, quick points to quick, jumps points to jumps, lazy points to lazy.

However, the following code seems to create these arrows eminating from the center of the sentence.

[image]

Can someone please assist?

```
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\tikzset{txtnode/.style={text width=3cm,outer sep=2pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \node (A) {The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog};
    \node[below left= 1cm and 0.1cm of A,txtnode] (B) {{quick}};
    \node[below = 1 cm of A,txtnode] (C) {\text{jumps}};
    \node[below right= 1cm and -0.4cm of A,txtnode] (D) {\text{lazy}};
    \foreach \n in {B,C,D} \draw[line width=1pt,->] (A) -- (\n);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what should present your image. Something like this:

[image]

Considering (now deleted) @carlatex answer, your first image can be reproduced by

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 1mm,
every node/.style = {font=\sffamily, outer sep=2pt}
                        ]
\node (A) {The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog};
\node (B) [below left=of A]    {quick};
\node (C) [below=of A]         {jumps};
\node (D) [below right=of A]   {lazy};
    \foreach \n in {B,C,D} \draw[line width=1pt,->] (A) -- (\n);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

However, if you like to connect by arrows the same words in both image lines, than the use `\subnode` defined in the `tikzmark` package can be a desired solution.

**Edit**
Here is an example how to use `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
    node distance = 7mm and 1mm,
every node/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\sffamily},
every edge/.style = {draw, line width=1pt,-Straight Barb}
                        ]
\node (A) {The \subnode{s1}{quick} brown fox \subnode{s2}{jumps} over the \subnode{s3}{lazy} dog};
\node (a) [below left=of A]     {quick};
\node (b) [below=of s2]          {jumps};
\node (c) [below right=of A]    {lazy};
\draw[->]   (s1) edge (a)   (s2) edge (b)   (s3) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
short notes about draw arrows between words, math variables and symbols outside `tikzpicture` environments.

As noted @Andrew Stacey in his comment, in such a cases you should use `\tikzmark`, `\pgfmark` or `\tikzmarknode`, `\subnode` is intended for use inside nodes in `tizpictures` only.

Details of their use id described in package/library documentation, which is part of your LaTeX installation or you can find it on [CTAN](https://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf).

A few examples:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{TM/.style = {% TikzMark
    overlay, remember picture,
    node distance = 7mm and 5mm,
every node/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small\sffamily},
every edge/.style = {draw=red, semithick, line width=1pt,-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=center}
        }}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\vspace*{3\baselineskip} % make space for the tikzpicture

Use of \verb+\pgfmark+ around some in text \pgfmark{As}words\pgfmark{Ae} in text enable draw \pgfmark{Bs}arrows\pgfmark{Be} between them or to their labels:

\begin{tikzpicture}[TM]
\coordinate[above=1ex of $(pic cs:As)!0.5!(pic cs:Ae)$]  (a);
\coordinate[above=1ex of $(pic cs:Bs)!0.5!(pic cs:Be)$]  (b);
%
\draw   (a) edge[pos=1.2, "ABCD"] ++ (0,1)
        (a) edge[bend left, "arrow" above] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

A node around \tikzmarknode[draw=blue]{a}{some words} in text means that we can
connect selected word in text together as well connect them with elements in maths environment \tikzmarknode[draw=blue]{b}{together}:
\[
\tikzmarknode{c}{\sum_{k=1}^n} k^{\tikzmarknode{d}{2}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[TM]
\draw   (a) edge (b)
        (a) edge (c)
        (c.south) edge[bend right=90, looseness=2] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\[
\tikzmarknode{a}{W} = \tikzmarknode{b}{F} \cdot \tikzmarknode{c}{D}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[TM]
\coordinate[below left=of a,  label=below:Work]     (A);
\coordinate[below=of b,       label=below:Force]    (B);
\coordinate[below right=of c, label=below:Distance] (C);
%
\path   (a) edge (A)    (b) edge (B)    (c) edge (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\vspace{2\baselineskip} % make space for tikzpicture
\]
\lipsum[1][3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko. Thank you for the answer. I am asking whether we can adjust these arrows so quick points to quick, jumps points to jumps (as shown already) and lazy points to lazy. At the moment the starting point of these arrows is clusters towards some random location in the middle, i.e., brown is pointing to quick. Is there a way to adjust?

Comment: @ Zarko I think what OP wants it that the arrow starts at the word quick in the sentence and points to the word quick below. The middle arrow starts in the center of the word jump (in the sentence) and points to jump and so on.

Comment: @Roland, I suspect that, so I in the first answer mentioned that probably the use of the `tikzmark` library is what he is after. Now I add an example how to use it.

Comment: @Norman, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer, but I guess subnode won't work if the original sentence is in math mode. For example, $a = b + c$ and let a point to a, b point to b, c point to c. Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @Norman, in your question you nor ask for such case. In math node you should use `\tikzmarknode{<name>}{<math expression>}` and add option `overlay` to picture, where you collect descriptions of equation. If this is what you like to have, than your question is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491915.

Comment: Subnode works just fine in an equation, it picks up the surrounding math mode and applies it to its contents, as does tikzmarknode.  The difference is that subnode is meant to be used within another node whereas tikzmarknode is meant to be used in normal text (so not inside a tikz picture).

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thank you for information. I will test solution with use of `subnode` in math environment ASAP.

Comment: No problem. If you can think of something I could add to the documentation - or an example - that would make it clearer then do suggest it.

Comment: Already voted for this, but if I could vote again I would.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thank you very much! I hope that my addendum is correct and that it will be of some help to readers.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a simple  `tabular` environment and `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\centering\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 & The \rnode[lb]{Q}{quick}~brown fox \rnode[b]{J}{jumps}~over the \rnode[rb]{L}{lazy}~dog \\[3ex]
\rnode [rt]{Q2}{quick} &
\hskip1.4em \rnode[t]{J2}{jumps} &
\rnode [lt]{L2}{lazy}
\psset{nodesep=0.5ex, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1}
\foreach \s/\t in {Q/Q2,J/J2,L/L2}{\pcline{->, linecolor=IndianRed}(\s)(\t)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, however, that it might be easier to do this with the [forest (links to CTAN)](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest?lang=en) package. I.e.,

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}  
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.},s sep=20mm
[quick] [jumps] [fox]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

It'll generate the following:
[image]

These are definitely not exactly arrows going from the sentence, but if the arrow bit isn't essential, then forest does the job much better, I think; the syntax is much simpler. At the same time, forest is based on TikZ. It's used by linguists for trees (apart from the documentation which is great, see, e.g., [here](https://dozernyi.gitlab.io/lsalatex/docs/pages/trees.html)).