# arrows in mathematical expressions with words

Tags: math-mode, amsthm, stacking-symbols

I would like to know how I can type the following mathematical expression
[image]

Notice I have the arrows pointing at the letters

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619925

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of the ways, using [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$$
\tikz[overlay, cyan]\draw[<-] (0.3,0.7) |- node[pos=1, anchor=east]{second order} (0,1);
\tikz[overlay, cyan]\draw[<-] (1.6,0.7) |- node[pos=1, anchor=west]{first order} (2,1);
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3-4y=e^x
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]