# Arrow to an equal symbol in a equation to justify it

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrows, unicode-math

My question's very simple: Is possible to do this?
[image]

I only want to know if this's possible and how to do it. Doesn't matter the arrow color. Of couse, I've made this in another app, the text belong's to LaTeX  but the arrow doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Try with Ti*k*Z and its library `tikzamrk`. As an example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491915/how-can-i-properly-write-this-equation-in-latex/#491934

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `\mathclap` macro of the `mathtools` package and the `\substack` macro of the `amsmath` package. (Aside: the `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable docuemnt class
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % optional, for \rotatebox macro

\begin{document}
\[
a+b\underset{\substack{\color{red}\uparrow \\ % or: \rotatebox{90}{$\longrightarrow$}
                       \mathclap{\textup{\tiny commutative}} \\  
                       \mathclap{\textup{\tiny property}}}}{=}b+a
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks you !

Answer (score 5):

With https://www.mathcha.io/editor it is very simple to do it. Here there is an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (192,108) -- (192,66) ;
\draw [shift={(192,64)}, rotate = 90] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
\draw (192,53) node  [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$a+b=b+a$};
\draw (121,108) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {commutative property};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An example to use `tikzmark` library, as I mentioned in my comment above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\[
a + b 
    \tikzmarknode[inner xsep=3pt]{A}{ = }
        b + a
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten <=1mm,
                    nodes={font=\small, text=black, align=center}]
\draw[thick, red, Straight Barb-] (A.south) -- ++ (0,-1) node[below] {commutative\\ property};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{17mm}
\]
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

After three compilation the result is:

[image]

Comment: @LSpice, you are right, I will correct this ASAP.l

Comment: The referenced [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659260/arrow-to-an-equal-symbol-in-a-equation-to-justify-it#comment1640469_659260).