# Displaying an arrow underneath a symbol

Tags: code

This is probably easily answered, but how can I get this image in code?

[image]

I have got something like this:

```
\begin{gathered}
    A=(\circ, \bullet, \bullet).\\
\underset{\text { Position } 1}{\uparrow}
\end{gathered}
```

But I am not really satisfied with this. Any ideas?

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491915/ can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\underset` together with a command that places the text in a zero width box, but with the possibility of moving it with respect to the arrow.

The first argument to `\showpos` is the fraction of the width that should be left of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\showpos}[2]{% #1 = factor, #2 = text
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      $\uparrow$ \\
      \makebox[\dimexpr#1\width*2\relax][l]{#2}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
A=(\underset{\showpos{0.3}{Position 1}}{{\circ}},{\bullet},{\bullet})
\]

\[
A=({\circ},\underset{\showpos{0.5}{Position 2}}{{\bullet}},{\bullet})
\]

\[
A=({\circ},{\bullet},\underset{\showpos{0.7}{Position 3}}{{\bullet}})
\]

\end{document}
```

Some visual formatting is necessary, depending on the whole formula.

[image]